# Easy way to show and compare means of normally vs. non-normally distributed distributions for continuous variables in gtsummary

Tags: gtsummary

I have a data frame with continuous and factor-type columns. I'm trying to build a summary table with gtsummary stratifying by a variable.
My question is as follows:

1. Is there a way to test all numerical variables at one to decide if their distribution is normal (shapiro.test() for example) using one of the apply family functions?
2. After doing so, is there a way to tell gtsummary so show normally distributed data as mean(sd) and non-normally distributed data as median(IQR)?
3. Can gtsummary decide whether to use methods for comparison of the means according to the distribution? (t test vs. Mann Whitney U test for example).

Thank you!

FC.

Comment: can you provide sample data? and some code you have tried ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would try something like this. I am using the Iris dataset as an example.
To answer your first question I would use sapply and use the shapiro.test to get if the data is normally distributed. I used the p-value to determine if it was normally distributed but you can substitute your own criteria if there is something more appropriate. After the first step you have two vectors one specifying which variables are normally dist and ones that are not. then you can pass that vector to gtsmmary to tell it to modify the test and statistics for those variables. you do not need to pass it for the non-normally distributed variables bc that is the default.

```
library(gtsummary)
library(dplyr)

normvals <- sapply(iris[sapply(iris, is.numeric)], function(x){
    normtest <- shapiro.test(x)
    #output pvalue
    normtest$p.value
})

notnorm <-  names(normvals[normvals <.05])

norm <- names(normvals[normvals >= .05])


irisdf <- filter(iris, Species != "setosa") %>% 
          mutate(Species = as.character(Species))


    
tbl_summary(irisdf, 
          by = Species,
          statistic = list(all_of(norm) ~ "{mean} ({sd})")) %>% 
add_p(
  test = list(all_of(norm) ~ "t.test"
  ))
```

Edit: you can hard code the variables into the gtsummary call so you can make sure it works on the version that is on CRAN as of 9/22/2020:

```
tbl_summary(irisdf, 
          by = Species,
          statistic = list(c('Sepal.Width', 'Sepal.Length') ~ "{mean} ({sd})")) %>% 
add_p(
  test = list(c('Sepal.Width', 'Sepal.Length') ~ "t.test"
  ))
```

Comment: Mike thank you so much for you quick response! I try to run exactly that code but I keep gettin the following error: Error in `statistic=` argument input. Select from ‘Sepal.Length’, ‘Sepal.Width’, ‘Petal.Length’, ‘Petal.Width’, ‘Species’. I tried to add statistic = list(all_of(norm)~ etc. etc. but it keeps showing the same error...any idea?

Comment: I might be using a dev version of the package that is not on github yet, but can you try `statistic = list(norm ~...)`? If that does not work then I will try to troubleshoot more

Comment: It keeps giving me the same error :(. I'm using R 4.0.2 the last one available).

Comment: I updated the answer with hard coded variables  as an example, you can then put yours in a vector in gtsummary and it should work with the version that is on CRAN

Comment: note that in the edited example I put in two variables to show how it is done, but in your case you would put in the variables that are normally dist

Comment: Thank you Mike!. Any idea why it wouldn't take the object "norm"? That would make things so much easier when there are many continuous variables to be included in the table...

Comment: my guess is that it has to do when it evaluates the call. If `tbl_summary` tried to execute the function before evaluating `norm` to a vector then it will throw the error. This will be fixed in future versions of `gtsummary`

Comment: A new version of gtsummary is out and I believe you should be able to pass the norm vector to tbl_summary and add_p

Comment: Thanks a lot! It seems to work (at least in the example using the "iris" df. With my data, I need to clean it before I run since I have some string rows causing trouble with the statistics.

Comment: Non-standard column names will be allowed in the next version of gtsummary, but for now I think you will have to use a more standard naming convention and then use labels for the variables.